# Magento 2 REST API get categories names by list of ids

Tags: category, product-attribute, magento2.2, rest-api

If you use Magento's REST APIs to get product, you use this endpoint:

```
GET /V1/products/{sku}
```

This endpoint returns response with category_ids in it.
What I want to do is to get the product with category names instead of ids.
I tried using `GET /V1/categories/list` with some search criteria and it worked but this endpoint needs admin privileges which can't be provided to show categories of a product inside the application for guest or registered customer without admin authorization.

The question is, can I do such a thing without building a custom endpoint that gets me either category names by list of ids or a product with categories names instead of ids?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes you can create your custom end point without asking for Access Token/ Authorization to get the category with its name.**

**Below is the steps :**

create **webapi.xml** file in your **VendorName/ModuleName/etc** directory.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
    <route url="/V1/customrouter/customcategorylistingurl/" method="GET">
        <service class="VendorName\ModuleName\Api\CustomCategoryListingInterface" method="getcategorylisting"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
</routes>
```

Create a di.xml file in your **VendorName/ModuleName/etc** directory and put below code in it.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="VendorName\ModuleName\Api\CustomCategoryListingInterface"
                type="VendorName\ModuleName\Model\CustomCategory" />
</config>
```

Now in your Custom Model(CustomCategory) - add the code(logic) for get all the categories with the category name then using above endpoint you will get the categories with the name.

**Note : As mention above in your webapi.xml file you must pass ref as anonymous - this parameter is used for guest use which will not asked for authorization.**